# Dojox charting, problem with Columns chart type

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I can't figure out what's wrong. Using the latest everything from dojotoolkit.org. My chart renders fine for a Marker or Line chart:

```
        this.chartVol.addPlot("default", {
            type: "MarkersOnly",
            lines: false,
            markers: false,
            gap: 1,
            hAxis: 'volX',
            vAxis: 'volY'
        });
```

but when I change to "Columns" I get nothing.

```
        this.chartVol.addPlot("default", {
            type: "Columns",
            lines: false,
            markers: false,
            gap: 1,
            hAxis: 'volX',
            vAxis: 'volY'

        });
```

I'm looking at this howto page, it's not clear what I'm doing wrong.

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html#dojox-charting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what you do wrong from the snippets you published. Some stuff is strange but appears harmless, like `gap` for `MarkersOnly` or `lines` and `markers` for `Columns`. Make sure that you do define axes named `volX` and `volY`.

One big difference between lines and columns is the data. While the lines (default) plot accepts an array of numbers or `{x, y}` points, the columns plot (prior to 1.5) accepts only an array of numbers (for obvious reasons `x` cannot be plotted with columns).

You said you use the latest everything, so I assume you are running the beta version of 1.5 — it should work, but I cannot say what's wrong from your snippets, sorry. Need more info.

Comment: I think I must be using an older version, because from your answer, I realize that I am using {x,y} points. which seem to work fine with Markers, but apparently not columns. I'm using 1.4.3 from the Google CDN

Comment: Try the SVN checkout, or nightly, or wait for 1.5 to be released (really soon now). Columns (and related plots) understand {x, y} notation now, but ignores x using and index instead. See if it fits your data model.